# Printing docx by Java

Tags: java, ms-word, free, docx

How to pass **/** send a pre-designed `.docx` file to a printer to be printed *, without open MS Word,* **by Java** using either **native** libraries or other **free** 3rd party libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few options:

- Use [LibreOffice to open the document and print it](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jlop/). This should provide reasonably good results without the need for a MS Word License / Windows.
- Use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) to open the document, extract the information you want and print it yourself using the Java Print API. Unless you're processing known documents this will be exceedingly difficult.
- Use Microsoft Word through COM (this may meet your requirement, since no Word window needs to actually open, it'll run in the background), open the document and print it. This will require use of the [Java COM Bridge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) which has some nasty native requirements and would require Windows.

Comment: Is the document style (font-size, alignment, header, and footer) will be kept if I use Apache POI?

Comment: With POI it's possible to get all of those things but you'd be responsible for actually drawing them. POI doesn't give you a good way to turn a document into something printable it only helps you read the document.